Tri-state input
I'm familiar with tri-state outputs. They can be high, low or high-impedance.
Now I read somewhere that tri-state inputs can detect wether they are connected or not.
Aren't digital inputs always high-impedance?
How does a tri-state input detect wether it is connected? I can only assume that you'll compare the voltages between two different input impedances.
Is the high-impedance state of a tri-state output not usually achieved by turning the IO pin to input mode?

Where is "somewhere"?

@vir https://forum.digikey.com/t/tri-state-logic-input-outputs/25183

I would take this article with a grain of salt. "Tri-state is also very common in programming" it says. What? Tri-state is primarily a hardware-term for sure.

I have heard of many weird things but not about "three state inputs". Would you explain what you mean by that term?

@Justme, the OP's taken it straight from the referenced article, which is not short on fallacies.

With a little squinting, one could apply the term 3-state input to something like case of many I2C chips, where the chip's address is set by setting input pins to either High, Low, or Not Connected (floating).

@Piglet the link to digikey forum belongs in the question, not in a comment

I find the term "three state input" somewhat confusing. It's not generally used as it is not accurate. I know you mean a "three level input" and that term is used, for example by Wolfson WM8741.
Obviously, you can make an input detect if it is tied high, or tied low, or not tied to anything and left floating, but even if the pin can detect between three states, it can't be called a three state input.
There are many ways this could be implemented.
You can detect between low/medium/high voltage range if it's not a digital input pin, but an analog input pin, which biases the pin weakly into the middle range, and can detect with comparators if it is externally connected to be in the upper third range or lower third range.
But as the pin is biased to midpoint, you can't really call that a high-impedance input, because a normal high impedance input means the input is really high impedance, as the opposite of it is an input which has either internal pull-ups or pull-downs, or both enabled.
If it were a pin that can detect more states like 256, it would be called an analog input pin that goes into an ADC. But an ADC alone cannot do anything else that read pin voltage, it can't determine if a pin is externally left floating if it is a high impedance input.
However, an analog or digital pin can be used to test if it is tied high or low or left floating, because a MCU can enable pull-downs an read the state, and then enable pull-up and read the state, so if the weak pull up or weak pull-down had no effect, the pin is not left floating but tied to low or high. Same can be tried with the ADC input to have even more states, and the MCU may allow to enable both pull-ups and pull-downs simultaneously, to approximate bias the pin to middle level, so it can be measured with ADC conversion if it is tied low, tied high, or left floating - but the input will not be in High-Z mode ever, or you measure garbage.

"I have heard of many weird things but not about "three state inputs"."
I have.
Linear Tech, Maxim, et al have tri-state inputs on many of their power supply and hot swap control chips.  Ground a pin for one function, tie it to Vcc for a second, or leave it floating for a third.  Of course, I can't remember any specific part numbers right now.
Internally there are two comparators.  These can be as simple as 1 transistor and a couple of diodes, not a full-blown LM311-type circuit.  The comparators combine for three internal control signals:  greater than me, less than him, or other.
Update:  IIRC, Maxim has a fan speed control chip that gets more I2C addresses with fewer pins by using tri-state inputs.

As per my comment above with regard to I2C chips.  Detecting three states is easy using normal DIO methods, as long as the signal lines are designed to handle both input and output logic probing from the uC (typically just series resistors).  If that's the case, then there's no need for specialized/additional glue logic.

And many other chips are like this. Sone have even more levels. And may use a DAC for reading. I would not call it a three-state input though. The article just blindly says there are 3-state inputs, but provides nothing to back up the term. Sure, I can write a program that enables internal pull ups, reads state, then enables internal pull-dows, and read the state again, to determine if someone externally ties the line high, low, or lets it float. I can also put a capacitor there and measure how long it takes to toggle state to have really weird amount of input states based on the capacitance.

Here's one way to do it on a chip (it really doesn't make much sense to do it outside of a chip in most cases†):

If you tie Vin to Vdd then A is high. Leave it open and B is high. Ground it and C is high.
The MOSFETs are adjusted in dimensions (I adjusted the widths in this case) so the thresholds are different fractions of Vdd.
† There are ways to do it with an MCU pin that may make sense in some cases.
